# azure maps differentiate address from point of interest

Tags: c#, azure-maps

I would like to be able to differentiate an address given by a user, by a point of interest.
For example, if I make an address reasearch with "Assemblée nationale" (which is a part of the parliament), I get a street called "assemblée nationale" in Versailles, instead of the parliament in Paris.
Of course, it works with the Point Of Interest research.

Is it possible with Azure Maps, to 'detect' that what the user inputs is an address or a point of interest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure Maps [fuzzy search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchfuzzy). You can check the "type" field for results in API response to see whether a search result is a POI or a street.

Here are the supported result type:
POI,
Street,
Geography,
Point Address,
Address Range,
Cross Street